# "Special device does not exist"

Tags: mount, raid

I have 3 hard drives in my machine. Two of them are 1TB drives with my old home partition on a software RAID1. I installed an SSD as a 3rd drive with a fresh Ubuntu 10.10 currently running. I now try to mount my old home partition, which gives me an error:

```
$ mount -t reiserfs /dev/sda5 /mnt/oldhome
mount: special device /dev/sda5 does not exist
```

fdisk shows me that all partitions are there. /dev has sda and sdb in it, but not the partitions on them.

Any ideas?

**edit:**

`blkid` shows me the following:

```
/dev/sda: TYPE="isw_raid_member" 
/dev/sdb: TYPE="isw_raid_member" 
/dev/mapper/isw_eahifbiigj_datadump1: UUID="247dbff9-236f-4fa7-a0d4-1f060d973a3e" TYPE="reiserfs" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="6ba699d7-caaa-4a87-9deb-e7aca73984de" TYPE="ext4"
```

I can mount the third one, which contains some orphaned partition, living on sda1.

Answer (score 2):

DM-RAID (the variant of RAID in use here, sometimes also known as SATA RAID, BIOS RAID, or fake RAID) creates a separate device for the whole array and suppresses the partitions for the component devices.  In other words, `/dev/sda5` is only the redundant half of your old home partition on your first disk, rather than the whole thing.

On Ubuntu 10.10, I believe that partition 5 of your array should be on `/dev/mapper/isw_eahifbiigj_datadump15`.  From Ubuntu 11.04, this will move to `/dev/mapper/isw_eahifbiigj_datadump1p5`.

Comment: The next day, suddenly everything is as I had expected before. No clue, what happened. `/dev/mapper` contains only one file: `control`.

Comment: So, after many problems after updating to 11.04, I decided to do a reinstall with 11.04. Now I have the following entries in /dev/mapper: `control`, `cryptswap1 -> ../dm-3`, `isw_eahifbiigj_datadump -> ../dm-0`, `isw_eahifbiigj_datadump1 -> ../dm-1`, `isw_eahifbiigj_datadump2 -> ../dm-2`, with none of them being the md-raid or part of it.

Comment: Sometimes the raid is there, sometimes it isn't. Is there an mdadm replacement, that interferes with mdadm? Should I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed similar problem by changing the mount line in /etc/fstab from /dev/mapper/isw_*Volume01 to /dev/mapper/isw*_Volume0p1

NOTE! The extra small "p" in there. I.e Volume01 -> Volume0p1