# Mount error special device /dev/sda1 does not exist

Tags: mount, data-recovery

This is related to my thread [askubuntu forumlink](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492095/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-ubuntu-12-04lts)

Right now i am stuck in recovering the data part. I just rebooted through a live usb of 13.04 (My original OS was 12.04LTS). But can't seem to be able to /dev/sda1 where all my data was. It's showing in gparted as well as sudo fdisk -l.

Sudo fdisk -l output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00052866

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   909690879   454844416   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       909692926   976766975    33537025    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       909692928   976766975    33537024   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

But when i try to mount it using  "sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/" it throws me an error 
"mount: special device /dev/sda1 does not exist", and when i try this "sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt/" it throws me an error
mount: unknown filesystem type 'isw_raid_member'

Any clue how to solve this thing. I really need to get my data back from that drive.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /dev/sda*`?

Comment: brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jul  9 07:51 /dev/sda

Comment: Oh... And you did reboot after creating any partitions on that disk, right?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this helps:
According what you write, you rebooted after creating the partition, it's old. And I assume you did not create new partitions on the disk since booting?
If that is true, this solution will not help, I think - but it will also do no harm (not change anything if it's ok already) - so you could just try:

Reread the partition table, in case the kernel did not yet notice a change there:

`sudo sfdisk -R`

The symptoms look like this is needed - don't know why.

(Let me know if it does help!)

See also [Marius Gedminas answer on "Mount error, special device does not exists"](https://askubuntu.com/a/334388/260447)

Comment: Sorry i think there was a misunderstanding. I never created any partitions. I am just trying to recover my data from my old os which is not booting anymore. But I think i spotted where the problem might be. This is the screenshot of one the drives it is detecting [link](http://i61.tinypic.com/2h3ufqp.png). As you can see it shows contents of 2.2GB whereas i says 25GB used. I think this is where my data is. Any clue how to recover that

Comment: No problem, just wanted to make sure it's not new. Hmmm... the 2.2GB versus 25GB is strange... Could it be that f602... is a directory inside the disk, not the root directory of the disk?

Comment: Shouldn't be cause that's the mountpoint. I even checked in gparted. Though there it says 9 GB used !! some serious inconsistencies here.

Comment: please note that in modern Linux distro's the command is `blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sdX`

Comment: @KDawG Thank you! It seems like the command can not directly do it for "all", right?

Comment: Hi @VolkerSiegel Yes it cannot, you have to explicitly specify the device with `blockdev`