# Cannot find root partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I have a problem with my laptop. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS next to Windows 8.1. It is the first time I am using Ubuntu. I don't know exactly what happened but somehow I damaged the Grub bootloader. So I am trying to recover it now and I am following this tutorial:

[English tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/6)

They both say, I have to mount my root partition.
So I am searching for it via

```
sudo gparted
```

which gives me the following:

... seems like I am not allowed to post the pictures here ...

so here is what `sudo parted -l` gives me:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA SanDisk SSD U100 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 16.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  16.0GB  16.0GB               HFS


Warning: /dev/sdb contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.
However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.
Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT
partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an
msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?
Yes/No? y                                                                 
Model: ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  1050MB  1049MB  ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      1050MB  1322MB  273MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, hidden
 3      1322MB  2371MB  1049MB  fat32           Basic data partition          hidden
 4      2371MB  2505MB  134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 5      2505MB  632GB   629GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      632GB   742GB   110GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 7      742GB   772GB   30.1GB  fat32                                         boot
12      772GB   943GB   171GB   ext4
13      943GB   951GB   8535MB  linux-swap(v1)
 8      951GB   952GB   472MB   ntfs                                          hidden, diag
 9      952GB   952GB   367MB   ntfs                                          hidden, diag
10      952GB   979GB   26.8GB  ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
11      979GB   1000GB  21.5GB  ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag


Model: SanDisk Ultra (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 16.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      98.3kB  16.0GB  16.0GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

According to the tutorial my root partition should be `/dev/sdb12` because it is in ext4-format, right?`

But when I try to mount it via

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb12 /mnt
```

it says

```
mount: special device /dev/sdb12 does not exist
```

A list of recognized drives and partitions by my system (`ls /dev/sd*`):

```
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1
/dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdb2  /dev/sdb3
/dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1
```

I really hope you can help me.

Comment: Have you tried `ls /dev/sd*` to see what partitions really exist (at least which are seen by your system)?

Comment: Also, when You want to fix grub You should check that out from Ubuntu live CD or pendrive: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @Jacajack: Thanks for your response. I already tried Boot-Repair without success.

This is what `sudo parted -l` gives me:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10790794/

´ls /dev/sd*' gives me this:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10790853/

Comment: So now Your problem is basically that You can't mount that partition, yes?

Comment: Yes. I am supposed to mount the sdb12 I guess but I can not do that.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not partitioning and disk expert, but I found [that askubuntu page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/334022/mount-error-special-device-does-not-exists). It describes problem similar to yours.  I hope it'll help you.

Comment: @DamBedEi : Until you can mount your '/' root (more so, your EFI partition), I guess you'll not be able to move forward to the EFI bits (and to edit your /etc/fstab), so first you'll have to determine to which is your EFI partition and which is your '/' root partition.  So from your Ubuntu live-DVD (or any rescue boot) you'll have to determine which partitions are what.  My preferences is to use 'sudo lsblk -fs'.  Once you've found out which partition is for EFI and which one is for EXT* (in your case, EXT4), you can move forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
Warning: /dev/sdb contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.
However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.
Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT
partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an
msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?
Yes/No? y
```

I started to write a response telling you how to fix it, but there are just too many decision points to do that without writing a small book. In the meantime, ***STOP USING THE DISK.*** Some possible configurations of that disk are ***DANGEROUS,*** and you might end up trashing important data if you write more data to the disk.

The simplest fix is to wipe the disk and start over. If you've got important user data, back up first. To do so safely, mount whatever you can read-only.

If you really need to recover it in place, it may be possible, but will require a number of checks and expertise to figure out the correct course of action. If you want to start this, please show the output of:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
```

...and also, the same `parted` output you showed, but use `unit s print` rather than simply `print`.

FYI, I expect that you used a GPT-unaware tool to partition the disk, which left you with an MBR disk with leftover GPT data. This configuration confuses `parted`. Somehow you managed to create new GPT partitions without damaging the MBR data. Windows' partitioning tools are known to create a fresh MBR without wiping GPT data, so installing Windows will sometimes do this.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your advice and started all over again. I ran Ubuntu with a USB-Stick in trial mode and tried to save everything I could. Now I am sitting infront of a complete naked PC again with Windows and Google Chrome. That's it :D